# AMD OpenCL Windows - Cmake cant find

Tags: windows, opencl, amd-gpu

I have just installed the AMD Catalyst driver:

https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/OpenCL2-Driver.aspx

However, after installation, I ran my CMake script and it says that OpenCL is not found. Searching in my disk, I do not see any OpenCL include folder either or any of those `cl.h` files. Is something broken with the Catalyst driver?

I just checked the install location, and the directory is empty too. FYI, I have a R7 370 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install [AMD APP SDK](https://developer.amd.com/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/) where you will be able to find OpenCL header files, libraries and so on.